# Laravel Image Uploading inserting temporary location and filename instead of correct name

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to upload an image to my database using Laravel, this is my first time trying to do this, but I want to do it correctly. The file is correctly uploading to the dedicated folder, but when it inserts it into the database it uses a a temporary name instead of the user set filename and extension. For example I want to upload a file named puppy.jpg, but its inserting into the database field as `/tmp/phplS7ToN`

**Model**

```
 public function insertPost($input)
{
    $validation = new Services\Validators\Post;

    if ($validation->passes())
    {

        return $post = Post::create($input);

        $image = Input::file('main_image');
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $upload = $image->move(Config::get('image.upload_folder'), $filename);

        Image::make(Config::get('image.upload_folder') . '/' . $filename)
            ->resize(Config::get('image.thumb_width'), null, true)
            ->save(Config::get('image.thumb_folder') . '/' . $filename);

        $post->main_image = $filename;
        $post->save();          
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using this

```
$filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
$filename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

You can only use this

```
$filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
```

This will return the file name you want. No need to use `pathinfo`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was following an incorrect tutorial then. Helpful as always @SheikhHeera :)

Comment: @MitchGlenn, Glad to help you, all the best.